# A single word for expressing 'Feeling like I am no one'

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What single word can be used for expressing 'I feel like I am no one'? Something which fits in the context of 'I feel so small in this vast universe'.

Comment: Hi Vpd, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! With single-word requests, it is essential that you provide at least one **sample sentence** where you might use the requested word. It would also be helpful to explain whether you've come across this word in the past, but have forgotten it (in which case, the more you can tell about the circumstances in which you've seen it, the better), or if you have no particular reason to think such a word exists, and are just hoping for the best.

Answer (score -1):

> 'I feel like a **feckless** midget in this vast universe'.

or

> 'I feel **feckless** in this vast universe'.

feckless  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/feckless)

> feeble and/or ineffective